# Is there a Perl or Python script I can write which can minimize the Gnome terminal window?

Tags: command-line, gnome, python, perl

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with the old-style GNOME setting from the GDM. (I don't like the new Unity interface.) Is there a way I can create a command that I can type in my terminal window to minimize it? It would be so awesome to simply type `min` and the terminal prompt minimizes while I focus on something else.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. First, install the `xdotool` command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Then, create an alias to be able to run *min* as a command:

   ```
   echo 'alias min="xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize"' >> ~/.bashrc`
   ```
3. Reload the *.bashrc* file:

   ```
   . ~/.bashrc
   ```

Answer (score 8):

The following python oneliner will minimize the current `gnome-terminal` window:

```
python3 -c "from gi.repository import Gdk; \
[ Gdk.Screen.get_default().get_active_window().iconify() for i in range(2)]"
```

Note that we need to call [iconify()](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#gdk-window-iconify) two times to minimize the window.

Comment: IIRC , you can run iconify twice, or you can store window object to variable, run `.iconify()` and then run `window.process_all_updates()`

Answer (score 2):

You can just use keybindings of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open the window menu, then press <kbd>N</kbd> (in an English locale) to minimize the window.